# sqlite 3 and string replacing

Tags: mysql, string, sqlite

How to write this query in Sqlite3?

```
select distinct LEFT(pav, LOCATE(';',pav)) from table;
```

I have many rows with pav = "somename;34h3hhasheshashes43jh43jh4"

I can't find function LOCATE() in the Sqlite3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link to SQLite [functions](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_corefunc.html). They don't have an equivalent of MySQL's Locate.

You should just parse the result in the program you're receiving the data in.