# How to Update this data using SQL?

Tags: sql, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [How to replace string in SQLite?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9097458/how-to-replace-string-in-sqlite)

I have a table column data as

> /var/abc/23423423/Documents/apple.jpg
>
> /var/sdg/64444223/Documents/Banana.jpg

I want to update this column so that anything preceding /Documents is removed.
So output should be:

> /Documents/apple.jpg
>
> /Documents/Banana.jpg

How do I achieve this using UPDATE Statement of SQL?

Comment: SQL is the language. Which SQL-product are you working with? SQL-Server, MySQL, Postgres, Oracle...?

Comment: I am using SQLite. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this will work:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourfield = MID(yourfield,INSTR(yourfield,"/Documents/"));
```

`INSTR` locates the position of the string `/Documents/`, and `MID` gets everything beginning from there.

**Notes:**

1. This maybe won't work as you expect it when you have something like
   `/Documents/Documents/` in your path string.
2. Depending on your RDBMS
   `MID` and `INSTR` may not be available, but most RDBMS support them.

**Updates:**

After my reply you've updated that SQLite is the RDBMS of your choice - this makes things more difficult. There ain't no INSTR in SQLite, so most people will advise you to parse the result with a program, change it there and update the data then - for example in [this SO post.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8538599/sqlite-3-and-string-replacing)

However... since your two examples both have a fixed directory name length (in total 18 characters), there is the tiny chance that in your case you could do it slightly easier:

```
UPDATE yourtable
SET yourfield = SUBSTR(yourfield,18);
```

I haven't tried this yet, but maybe this works for you.

Comment: SQLite has no `INSTR()` function or equivalent. So, this is no easy task.

Comment: Sorry, this information wasn't provided as I was replying. I'll refine my answer to show how it's done n SQLite.